# How can I select on multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a web page, I have input elements, such as:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-initialstate="False">
```

The `initialstate` property is set when the page is built server-side.

In order to display a list of all checkboxes that were disabled, and are now disabled, I would like to make a jQuery selection, such as:

```
$(input and value = true and data-initialstate = false)
```

But I can't find the correct syntax. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Does _initialstate_  is manipulate after page load?

Comment: No, it is set by the Razor engine during page construction, and never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably by 'value = true' you mean checked checboxes. If so, to achieve this you can use the `:checked` and attribute selectors. Try this:

```
var $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox:checked[data-initialstate="False"]');
```

Note though, that this will not work if the `data` attribute is modified during the page lifetime. In that case you would need to use `filter()`, like this:

```
var $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox:checked').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).data('initialstate');
});
```